# Increase the number of e compilation errors reported

Tags: compiler-errors, specman, e

Is there option to increase the number of compilation errors, that are reported at the end of *e* compilation?

10 is too few for me

Comment: Which compiler / platform are you on?  GNU e on Linux?

Comment: @Scott'scm6079', according to the tag, it seems that the question is about the *e* verification language, and not about GNU E.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Specman has a configuration flag for this. You can use:

> set config misc -compilation_errors_num=*new_number*

The default value of this flag is 10, indeed.